# Does the "Supporting Multiple Screens" document contradict itself?

Tags: android

In the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) document in the Android Dev Guide, some [example screen configurations](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) are given.  One of them states that the `small-ldpi` designation is given to QVGA (240x320) screens with a physical size of 2.6"-3.0".  According to [this DPI calculator](http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html), a 2.8" QVGA display equates to 143 dpi.  However, further down the page the document [explicitly states](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) that all screens over 140 dpi are considered "medium" density.

So which is it, `ldpi` or `mdpi`?  Is this a mistake?  Does anyone know what the HTC Tattoo or similar device actually reports?  I don't have access to any devices like this.

Also, with the recent publishing of this document, I'm glad to see we *finally* have an explicit statement of the exact DPI ranges of the three density categories.  But why haven't we been given the same for the `small`, `medium`, and `large` screen size categories?  I'd like to know the exact ranges for all these.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So which is it, ldpi or mdpi?

`ldpi`, at least for the HTC Tattoo, using [`DensityMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) and its `densityDpi` field.

> Is this a mistake?

At minimum, it is unclear.

> But why haven't we been given the same
>   for the small, medium, and large
>   screen size categories?

DPI is for density. Density has nothing to do with size. Ergo, there cannot be DPI ranges for size.

Table 1 shows size buckets in inches compared to labels (`small`, `normal`, `large`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

What I meant is, why don't I have specific diagonal measurements for each of those categories?  For example, the largest `normal` screen is 4.0" and the smallest `large` screen is 4.8".  So in that 0.8" gap, where does normal end and large begin?

Comment: @Neil Traft: Ah, I see what you mean. I can tell you that the EVO 4G, which has about a 4.3" diagonal, is `normal`.